# (Swift) Error when trying to load a local .css file

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

In my app I have a folder named `"CSS"` with file named `"style.css"` in it. 
When I try to load it, I get this error :

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the code where I am trying to load it :

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "style", ofType: "css", inDirectory: "CSS")!
let cssString = try! String(contentsOfFile: path).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: 1 - make sure you included `CSS/style.css` (case-sensitive) in resource bundle at build time; 2 - never force-unwrap, check for errors instead with if or guard, e.g. `guard let path = Bundle.main.path(...)`

Comment: The problem was in CSS folder. Everything works when I remove my style.css from CSS folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your file is present in the Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources list

dont force unwrap , check for errors like this

```
   guard Bundle.main.path(forResource: "style", ofType: "CSS") != nil else {
        return
    }

    do {

    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```